# Can I get a confirmation that a pending card transaction details are real?

Tags: fraud, debit-card, transaction, mastercard

I'm going to make a deal over the Internet with a payment onto my Mastercard debit card (for providing some service online); a part of the payment will be done up front. I'll have a (not editable or deletable) online conversation as a proof of the deal (I'll make sure to have it contain all the key agreement and payment details) in case they cancel the payment or something.

Since an international card payment can take up to a few days to complete, I'm going to ask the customer to provide transaction details so that I can get to work without waiting for the payment to complete.

Here's the question: **in the meantime, can I get a confirmation from someone that the transaction details provided are real -- i.e. that this transaction has indeed been created? If yes, what exact transaction details will I need to provide?**

I already phoned into my bank and they said they cannot do that because they only see a transaction once it reaches them. I also checked the official Mastercard site, and they only publish a support contact to report a lost or stolen card.

clarification from the comments: the card is issued by my bank and tied to my bank account. I expect the customer to use their bank's web site or some other online service to initiate a card-to-card transfer.

Comment: This is a question for your merchant, that is, the service you are paying to accept credit card payments. Even if you can see an authorization it doesn't mean it will post, and even if it posts it doesn't mean they can't reverse it.

Comment: @HartCO the card is issued by my bank and tied to my bank account. I expect the customer to use their bank's web site or some other online service to initiate a card-to-card transfer. Who will be the "merchant" then?

Comment: "a (**not editable** or deletable) online conversation as a proof of the deal"   I'm more than a bit dubious about that.

Comment: *I expect the customer to use their bank's web site or some other online service to initiate a card-to-card transfer.* You may be quite aware of this, but that's not really a typical method for making payments for services. More typical would be for the vendor (you, I think?) to process the transaction through a point of sale device or service (which would allow a hold to be placed, making the reassurance you're seeking automatic). Or to use an escrow agent or payment service such as Paypal. Or, use an established network that's meant for account-to-account transactions (i.e. ACH).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment to the question:

> the card is issued by my bank and tied to my bank account. I expect
>   the customer to use their bank's web site or some other online service
>   to initiate a card-to-card transfer. Who will be the "merchant" then?

You need to talk to your bank about the buyers ability to reverse a card-to-card transfer.

It appears that you don't have a account for you to pull money from the customers account or to charge a customers credit card.  That may mean that you are using a personal account as a business account. That might violate the terms of service of your bank account.

The lack of ability for you to start the transaction by putting a hold on their account for the agreed amount, may mean that you will have to wait until the money arrives and the ability to reverse the transfer expires before you know that you probably have the funds.

Any information they show you from their banking screen can be faked, or cancelled. Their bank will not confirm the transaction for you because you aren't their customer.